# Является ли класс по работе с сессиями корректным и безопасным?

Tags: php, безопасность, инспекция-кода, сессия

У меня есть вопрос по работе с сессиями. Я реализовал класс для работы с сессиями, но точно не могу определить его адекватность и корректность.

```
<?php

namespace Core;


class Session
{
    /**
     * @var string Название сесии
     */
    private $name;
    /**
     * @var array Cookie сессии
     */
    private $cookie;
    /**
     * @var int Время жизни сессии
     */
    private $timeToLive;

    /**
     * Session constructor
     * @see https://php.ru/manual/session.configuration.html Настройка во время выполнения
     * @see https://php.ru/manual/function.session-set-cookie-params.html PHP session_set_cookie_params
     * @param int $time_to_live Время жизни сессии (в минутах)
     * @param string $name
     * @param array $cookie
     */
    public function __construct($time_to_live = 30, $name = "application.session", $cookie = [])
    {
        $this->timeToLive = $time_to_live;
        // Изменяется имя сеанса (по умолчанию) на указанное (если есть) имя для конкретного приложения
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->cookie = $cookie;
        // session.cookie_path определяет устанавливаемый путь в сессионной cookie
        // session.cookie_domain определяет устанавливаемый домен в сессионной cookie
        $this->cookie += [
            'lifetime' => 0,
            'path' => ini_get('session.cookie_path'),
            'domain' => ini_get('session.cookie_domain'),
            'secure' => isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']),
            'httponly' => true
        ];

        /*
         * Указывается, что сеансы должны передаваться только с помощью файлов cookie,
         * исключая возможность отправки идентификатора сеанса в качестве параметра «GET».
         * Установка параметров cookie идентификатора сеанса. Эти параметры могут быть переопределены при инициализации
         * обработчика сеанса, однако рекомендуется использовать значения по умолчанию, разрешающие отправку
         * только по HTTPS (если имеется) и ограниченный доступ HTTP (без доступа к сценарию на стороне клиента).
         */

        // Определяет, будет ли модуль использовать cookies для хранения идентификатора сессии на стороне клиента
        ini_set('session.use_cookies', 1);
        // Определяет, будет ли модуль использовать только cookies для хранения идентификатора сессии на стороне клиента
        ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1);
        session_set_cookie_params(
            $this->cookie['lifetime'],
            $this->cookie['path'],
            $this->cookie['domain'],
            $this->cookie['secure'],
            $this->cookie['httponly']
        );
    }

    public function __get($name)
    {
        switch ($name) {
            case 'isActive':
                return $this->getActive();
            case 'id':
                return $this->getId();
            case 'name':
                return isset($this->name) ? $this->name : $this->getName();
            case 'isValid':
                return $this->isValid();
        }
    }

    public function __set($name, $value)
    {
        switch ($name) {
            case 'id':
                $this->setId($value);
                break;
            case 'name':
                $this->setName($value);
                break;
            case 'timeToLive':
                $this->timeToLive = $value * 60;
                break;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Получение статуса активности сессии
     * @see https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.session-status.php PHP session_status
     * @return bool Статус активности сессии
     */
    private function getActive()
    {
        return session_status() === PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE;
    }

    /**
     * Получение идентификатора текущей сессии.
     * Метод является оберткой для реализации стандартного метода.
     * @see https://secure.php.net/manual/ru/function.session-id.php PHP session_id
     * @return string
     */
    private function getId()
    {
        return session_id();
    }

    /**
     * Получение имени сессии
     * Метод является оберткой для реализации стандартного метода
     * @see https://php.ru/manual/function.session-name.html PHP session_name
     * @return string|null
     */
    private function getName()
    {
        return $this->isActive ? session_name() : null;
    }

    private function isValid()
    {
        return !$this->isExpired() && $this->isFingerprint();
    }

    /**
     * Проверка срока действия сессии
     * @return bool
     */
    private function isExpired()
    {
        $activity = isset($_SESSION['_last_activity']) ? $_SESSION['_last_activity'] : false;
        if ($activity && ((time() - $activity) > $this->timeToLive)) {
            return true;
        }
        $_SESSION['_last_activity'] = time();

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Проверка клиента
     * @return bool
     */
    private function isFingerprint()
    {
        $hash = sha1($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] .
            (ip2long($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) & ip2long('255.255.0.0')));

        if (isset($_SESSION['_fingerprint'])) {
            return $_SESSION['_fingerprint'] === $hash;
        }

        $_SESSION['_fingerprint'] = $hash;

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Назначение идентификатора текущей сессии.
     * Метод является оберткой для реализации стандартного метода.
     * @see https://secure.php.net/manual/ru/function.session-id.php PHP session_id
     * @param string $id Идентификатор сессии для текущей сессии
     */
    private function setId($id)
    {
        session_id($id);
    }

    /**
     * Установка имени сессии
     * Метод является оберткой для реализации стандартного метода
     * @see https://php.ru/manual/function.session-name.html PHP session_name
     * @param $name
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        if ($this->isActive) {
            session_name($name);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Инициализация сессии
     */
    public function open()
    {
        // Бездействие, если сессия была инициализирована ранее
        if ($this->isActive) {
            return;
        }

        session_start();
        // Проверка на корректность инициализированнйо сессии
        if (!$this->isActive) {
            // TODO: Вывод исключения
        }
    }

    /**
     * Уничтожение сессии, включая все атрибуты. Метод имеет эффект только при наличии активной сессии.
     * @see https://php.ru/manual/function.setcookie.html PHP setcookie
     */
    public function destroy()
    {
        if ($this->isActive) {
            $this->deleteAll();
            setcookie(
                $this->name,
                time() - 42000,
                $this->cookie['path'],
                $this->cookie['domain'],
                $this->cookie['secure'],
                $this->cookie['httponly']
            );

            session_destroy();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Удаление всех значений сессии
     * Метод является оберткой для реализации стандартного метода
     * @see https://php.ru/manual/function.session-unset.html PHP session_unset
     */
    public function deleteAll()
    {
        if ($this->isActive) {
            session_unset();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Обновление текущего ID на новый. Метод имеет эффект только при наличии активной сессии.
     * @see https://secure.php.net/session_regenerate_id PHP session_regenerate_id
     * @param bool $delete_old_session
     */
    public function refresh($delete_old_session = true)
    {
        if ($this->isActive) {
            session_regenerate_id($delete_old_session);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Получение значение сессии по ключу.
     * @param string $key Ключ, по которому необходимо получить значения
     * @return null|mixed Значение сессии по ключу
     */
    public function get($key)
    {
        if ($this->isActive) {
            return isset($_SESSION[$key]) ? $_SESSION[$key] : null;
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Добавление или установка значений в сессию по ключу
     * @param string $key Ключ, в который необходимо добавить значения
     * @param string $value Значение добавления
     */
    public function set($key, $value)
    {
        if ($this->isActive) {
            $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Удаление значения сессии по ключу
     * @param string $key Ключ, по которому необходимо удалить значения
     */
    public function delete($key)
    {
        if ($this->isActive && isset($_SESSION[$key])) {
            unset($_SESSION[$key]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Проверка наличия ключа у сессии
     * @param string $key Ключ, в который необходимо найти
     * @return bool
     */
    public function hasKey($key)
    {
        return ($this->isActive && isset($_SESSION[$key]));
    }
}
```

Использование:

```
$session = new Session();
$session->open();
// If AFK more than access - logout
if (!$session->isValid) {
    $session->destroy();
}
...
```